# How do I make a python code that returns information for all pieces of data from a CSV file and not just one single piece?

Tags: python, file, csv

I'm writing a code based on this set of information (http://www.databasebasketball.com/players/playerlist.htm) put into a CSV file.

I want to make a code that determines the BMI of each player, then if their BMI is over 30, it will consider them obese.

How do I define a function that will be able to return information for every player, and not just one?

```
import csv

def read_csv(filename):
    """
    Reads a Comma Separated Value file,
    returns a list of rows; each row is a dictionary of columns.
    """
    with open(filename, encoding="utf_8_sig") as file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(file)
        rows = list(reader)
    return rows

# Try out the function
players = read_csv("players.csv")

# Print information on the first player, to demonstrate how
# to get to the data
from pprint import pprint
pprint(players[0])
print(players[0]["lastname"])
print(players[0]["weight"])


total_h_inches = int(players[0]["h_feet"]) * 12 + int(players[0]["h_inches"])


def obesity(bmi):
    bmi=(int(players[0]["weight"])/(total_h_inches**2))* 703
    if bmi >= 30:
        print ('player', players[0]["lastname"], 'is obese')
    else:
        print (('player', players[0]["lastname"], 'is not obese'))
print(obesity([0]))
```

It returns information for the first player, but I'm not sure how to edit the code so that it will work for any player

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most equivalent code I can think of is one that instead of sticking to `player[0]`, has a `for` loop that walks the whole list of `players`

```
for i in range(len(players)):
    pprint(players[i])
    print(players[i]["lastname"])
    print(players[i]["weight"])


    total_h_inches = int(players[i]["h_feet"]) * 12 + int(players[i]["h_inches"])


    def obesity(bmi):
        bmi=(int(players[i]["weight"])/(total_h_inches**2))* 703
        if bmi >= 30:
            print ('player', players[i]["lastname"], 'is obese')
        else:
            print (('player', players[i]["lastname"], 'is not obese'))
    print(obesity([i]))
```

This is very bad code, though:

- It keeps defining the `obesity` function for each iteration of the `for` loop.
- The `obesity` function receives `bmi` as a parameter, but `bmi` is actually calculated within the function (thus, the parameter is useless for the function)

I'd consider moving the `obesitiy` function before the `for` loop and have it accepting a `player` record to calculate said player's `obesity` (each of the `player` records in your `players` list contains all the information you need to know whether the player is obese or not, right?).

I'd do something like:

```
def is_obese(player):
    total_h_inches = int(player["h_feet"]) * 12 + int(player["h_inches"])
    bmi = (int(player["weight"])/(total_h_inches**2))* 703
    return bmi >= 30

for i in range(len(players)):
    if is_obese(players[i]):
         print ('player', players[i]["lastname"], 'is obese')
    else:
         print ('player', players[i]["lastname"], 'is not obese')
```

Or what's probably clearer, instead of walking the `players` list using the index (the numeric `i`) Python allows you to directly walk the *items* in the list:

```
for player in players:
    if is_obese(player):
         print ('player', player["lastname"], 'is obese')
    else:
         print ('player', player["lastname"], 'is not obese')
```

You probably want to check some tutorial about Python lists. Here's [one](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm), but there are tons out there.

### **EDIT:**

If you're getting some error while calculating the player's obesity, you can wrap the `is_obese` function call in a `try/except` block:

```
for player in players:
    try:
        if is_obese(player):
             print ('player', player["lastname"], 'is obese')
        else:
             print ('player', player["lastname"], 'is not obese')
    except ValueError:
        print ("I can't determine %s's obesity" % player['lastname'])
```

Comment: I tried something similar to this and it works for some of the data but then it returns this error:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '8.5'

Comment: what error? It didn't get added to the comment **:-)**

Comment: Ah, that's because `8.5` is not a valid string representation of an integer number, but a real (or `float`, rather). It looks like some players have a _whatever_ data that is not an `int`. Check the line where that happens. In that line, you'll see an `int(...whatever...)`. Change it to `float(...whatever...)`

Comment: Sorry to be a bother, but how do I change only the lines that need to be floats? Because if I change it to 
`total_h_inches = float(player["h_feet"]) * 12 + float(player["h_inches"])`
that doesn't work either and returns a different error.
Thanks

Comment: No bother :-). That type cast is good... What error are you getting now? Some key error, maybe?

Comment: Thanks! It says: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'NULL'`

Comment: Your input file is problematic, then... Some of the information is not a number, as you'd expect, but the string 'NULL'. That means that whatever data you're trying to evaluate (`h_feet` or `h_inches`) is not available for a particular player. If that's the case, you can't possibly know what's his `bmi` is, and therefore, you can't know if he's obese or not.

Comment: Yes it's because some of the players in the data are 6 or 7 feet and 0 inches tall. Is there a solution that would work for those special cases as well?

Comment: That's not really the scope of this question, but meh... here it goes: `total_h_inches = float(player["h_feet"]) * 12 + (float(player["h_inches"]) if player["h_inches"] != 'NULL' else 0)`

Comment: Btw (and this is **optional**), but if this answer solved your question, you might wanna select it as the chosen answer (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) Is good for you, for future reference and for me (I care most about that part) **:-P** It's good for everyone...

Comment: Yes it definitely did. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks. Glad I helped **:-)**. Also (going back to good reasons for choosing an answer...) I forgot to mention that _another_ good reason to choose an answer is that many users won't answer questions to people who systematically refuse to choose an answer (I mean... if no answer suits what you asked, then is fine not to choose one, but if it did, don't forget to click on that green check **;-)** )

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over players.

```
def obesity(players):
    for player in players:
        total_h_inches = int(player["h_feet"]) * 12 + int(player["h_inches"])
        bmi=(int(player['weight'])/(total_h_inches**2)) * 703
        if bmi >= 30:
            print(player['lastname'], 'is obese')
```

then:

```
obesity(players)
```